# Crash/misfunction of QFileDialog in debug builds

Tags: qt, visual-c++, qfiledialog

I know this post is quite old, but I'm experiencing the same kind of problem.

I'm using Qt 4.6 on Windows 7 64 bits, application is built with Visual Studio 2008.

I have the same kind of use of the `QFileDialog` class. In a slot of one of my widgets I try to open a "browse window" to select a file to open.

I've tried all combinations of the following:

- Native vs. `QFileDialog` instance on stack vs. `QFileDialog` instance on heap.
- "parent" parameter set as NULL vs. this vs. mainWindow
- `QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog` set to `true` or `false`

  ```
  const int cFILE_OPEN_DLG_TYPE = 0;
  #define FILE_OPEN_DLG_PARENT NULL
  //#define FILE_OPEN_DLG_PARENT this
  //#define FILE_OPEN_DLG_PARENT mMainWindow
  const bool cFILE_OPEN_DLG_NATIVE = false;

  void VgQtModelWidget::on_mBrowseButton_clicked()
  {
      QString lFilePath;
      QFileDialog::Options lOptions = (cFILE_OPEN_DLG_NATIVE ? QFileDialog::DontUseNativeDialog : 0);
      if (cFILE_OPEN_DLG_TYPE == 0) // Heap allocated dialog
      {
          QFileDialog* lFileDlg  = new QFileDialog (FILE_OPEN_DLG_PARENT);
          lFileDlg->setOptions(lOptions);
          lFileDlg->setWindowTitle(tr("Open model"));
          lFileDlg->setFilter(tr("Model file (*.vsg4)"));
          if (!lFileDlg->exec() || !lFileDlg->selectedFiles().size())
          {
              delete lFileDlg;
              return;
          }
          lFilePath = lFileDlg->selectedFiles().at(0);
          delete lFileDlg;
      }
      else if (cFILE_OPEN_DLG_TYPE == 1) // Stack allocated version
      {
          QFileDialog lFileDlg (FILE_OPEN_DLG_PARENT);
          lFileDlg.setOptions(lOptions);
          lFileDlg.setWindowTitle(tr("Open model"));
          lFileDlg.setFilter(tr("Model file (*.vsg4)"));
          if (!lFileDlg.exec() || !lFileDlg.selectedFiles().size())
          {
              return;
          }
          lFilePath = lFileDlg.selectedFiles().at(0);
      }
      else
      {
          lFilePath = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(FILE_OPEN_DLG_PARENT,tr("Open Model File"), tr("."), tr("Model file (*.vsg4)"), 0, lOptions);
      }
      QFile lFile (lFilePath);
      if (lFile.exists())
      {
          // do something with file...
      }
  }
  ```

This works flawless in release builds, but on debug builds here are the results:

#### Heap allocated dialog

All versions (native/non-native, parent=this/parent=null)  **CRASH**.

#### Stack allocated dialog

All versions (native/non-native, parent=this/parent=null)  **CRASH**.

#### Static helper

- native, whichever parent: getOpenFileName returns an empty string without showing anything
- native, whichever parent: **CRASH**

Thing is, when it is a crash, it is a really ugly one, with the call stack completely messed up. It really looks like some kind debug/non-debug mixup, but I have double-checked that QT_DEBUG is defined and that I link with the debug libraries for Qt.

Anyone has a clue ?

Comment: Well, the code you posted here looks harmless enough. So my first guess would be that the problem actually lies elsewhere. Something happens prior to this function being called that sets this function up for failure. In release mode, whatever is causing the problem is optimized away. Have you tried using this slot in a test app that has nothing more than a single button attached to it? Strip out everything you can and see if the problem still exists.

Comment: What says debugger? Where crash in Qt occurs?

Comment: @Dmitry When the crash occurs, the location may not be relevant, because the stack seems corrupted.

Comment: It's very strange. Try to do step-by-step debugging: place breakpoint on your call and step into it.
Are you sure, that you use qt 4.6 binaries for exact msvc 2008? Are you sure that include/libraries directories are correct?

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I have made a standalone example, but the crash does not occur with it.

Comment: I've tested by adding the file dialog creation code to my "main" function (before qApp.exec()) same behavior => crashes

Comment: It will be nice if you will provide sample code that I can compile and reproduce a crash. There are no telepathist who can debug your code without any samples.

Comment: I've tried, but as told before, the example does not crash. I think the problem comes from bad VS project settings. I'm still trying in the time I can allocate to this issue. I'm currently bypassing the problem by using a QInputDialog when running the debug version.